# Diagrams as visualizations of functors

Tags: category-theory, functors, quiver

Can this quiver $A\to B\to C$ be a diagram in some category? (Let's hope that now my question is "specific" so the community bot won't close it)

This is the background for me asking this: my prof used a weird definition of a diagram, and according to it the quiver I mentioned can be a diagram. But, it was a course in algebraic topology and she just used it to define pushout. So it's not unlikely that her definition is different from the one commonly used.

This is why I think it can't be a diagram (would like to hear if my understanding of a diagram is incorrect, because as I said, I didn't learn it in my courses):

A diagram of shape $J$ in the category $C$ is a functor $F:J \to C$. Namely, the relation between a functor and a diagram is the same as the relation between a vector field and its visual representation: diagram is a "visualization of a functor" by taking the structure of the domain $J$ and replacing the elements of $J$ with their images.

Just like in a vector field $\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}^{2}$: the visualization is to draw, in every point of the domain $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, the image of this point (which is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$).

Specifically, every diagram has "a structure of a category" ([some stuff I came up with](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4858827/quivers-as-the-underlying-structure-of-categories)). For example, this quiver $A\to B\to C$ is clearly not a structure of a category, therefore, it **can't** be a diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking whether a graph/quiver can be used as the shape for a diagram, rather than a category? The standard definition of diagram is indeed a functor, in which case a graph of shape $A \to B \to C$ is technically not a shape. However, one can easily fix this by taking the free category on the graph, and this is fairly typical in practice. Alternatively, it is possible to define shapes for limits in terms of graphs rather than categories. There is an extensive discussion of the advantages and disadvantages of this approach in the MathOverflow question [Shapes for category theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391627/shapes-for-category-theory).

> Namely, the relation between a functor and a diagram is the same as the relation between a vector field and its visual representation: diagram is a "visualization of a functor" by taking the structure of the domain 
> and replacing the elements of 
> with their images.

There is no formal distinction between a functor and a diagram. The distinction is purely conceptual: if someone calls a functor a "diagram", then they intend to take its limit or colimit. You should not conflate a diagram with its image in its codomain.

Comment: thanks! my prof defined diagrams with quivers just like in the question you mentioned :)